# Finding users from table that existed over 24 hours ago

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I need to write queries to find out *new users* and *regular users*.

*new users* are the ones whose uuid appeared in last 24 hours (from now minus the time query is fired) in `table2` and was not there before.

*regular users* are the ones whose uuid appeared in last day in `table2` and was also there at least once in the last 3 days.

In addition to this only records with `id > 10` and `ip != 2` are to be considered.

`table1` is a temporary table containing dates. I am not able to figure out how to achieve this with help of joins. Please help me.

---

## table2

```
    +----+---------------------+------+------+
    | id | ts                  | uuid | ip   |
    +----+---------------------+------+------+
    |  1 | 2010-01-10 00:00:00 | uid1 |    5 |
    |  2 | 2010-01-10 00:00:00 | uid2 |   14 |
    |  3 | 2010-01-10 00:00:00 | uid3 |   11 |
    |  4 | 2010-01-11 00:00:00 | uid4 |   16 |
    |  5 | 2010-01-11 00:00:00 | uid5 |    4 |
    |  6 | 2010-01-13 00:00:00 | uid6 |    2 |
    |  7 | 2010-01-10 00:00:00 | uid1 |    1 |
    |  8 | 2010-01-11 00:00:00 | uid2 |   10 |
    |  9 | 2010-01-12 00:00:00 | uid1 |    1 |
    | 10 | 2010-01-13 00:00:00 | uid4 |    1 |
    | 11 | 2010-01-09 21:00:00 | uid1 |    1 |
    | 12 | 2010-01-09 21:30:00 | uid1 |    2 |
    | 13 | 2010-01-10 05:00:00 | uid2 |    3 |
    | 14 | 2010-01-10 12:00:00 | uid1 |    1 |
    | 15 | 2010-01-10 12:00:00 | uid3 |    1 |
    | 16 | 2010-01-10 21:00:01 | uid1 |    7 |
    | 17 | 2010-01-11 01:00:00 | uid2 |   14 |
    | 18 | 2010-01-11 05:00:00 | uid2 |   11 |
    | 19 | 2010-01-11 17:59:00 | uid4 |   13 |
    | 20 | 2010-01-11 06:00:00 | uid5 |   12 |
    | 21 | 2010-01-11 18:01:00 | uid1 |   14 |
    | 22 | 2010-01-12 23:05:00 | uid4 |   17 |
    | 23 | 2010-01-13 12:01:23 | uid6 |   13 |
    +----+---------------------+------+------+
    23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

## table1

```
    +------------+
    | ts         |
    +------------+
    | 2010-01-10 |
    | 2010-01-11 |
    | 2010-01-12 |
    | 2010-01-13 |
    +------------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

## Output in case of *new users* taken at 18:00

```
+------------+-------+
| ts         | users |
+------------+-------+
| 2010-01-10 |     3 |
| 2010-01-11 |     2 |
| 2010-01-12 |     0 |
| 2010-01-13 |     1 |
+------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

## MySQL table dump

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `ts` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('2010-01-10'),('2010-01-11'),('2010-01-12'),('2010-01-13');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table2`;
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES (1,'2010-01-10 00:00:00','uid1',5),(2,'2010-01-10 00:00:00','uid2',14),(3,'2010-01-10 00:00:00','uid3',11),(4,'2010-01-11 00:00:00','uid4',16),(5,'2010-01-11 00:00:00','uid5',4),(6,'2010-01-13 00:00:00','uid6',2),(7,'2010-01-10 00:00:00','uid1',1),(8,'2010-01-11 00:00:00','uid2',10),(9,'2010-01-12 00:00:00','uid1',1),(10,'2010-01-13 00:00:00','uid4',1),(11,'2010-01-09 21:00:00','uid1',1),(12,'2010-01-09 21:30:00','uid1',2),(13,'2010-01-10 05:00:00','uid2',3),(14,'2010-01-10 12:00:00','uid1',1),(15,'2010-01-10 12:00:00','uid3',1),(16,'2010-01-10 21:00:01','uid1',7),(17,'2010-01-11 01:00:00','uid2',14),(18,'2010-01-11 05:00:00','uid2',11),(19,'2010-01-11 17:59:00','uid4',13),(20,'2010-01-11 06:00:00','uid5',12),(21,'2010-01-11 18:01:00','uid1',14),(22,'2010-01-12 23:05:00','uid4',17),(23,'2010-01-13 12:01:23','uid6',13);
```

Comment: Now *that's* how to ask a DB question. Clear, with sample data ready to copy-and-paste.

Comment: Except: What's `table2` for? Is it to limit the range of dates you get this info for?

Comment: Actually, you've mislabelled your tables. What's the table of dates (table2 in your text, table1 in the sample) for?

Comment: Ya I mislabled the tables :(. now I have corrected that.

Comment: table1 is to limit date range

Comment: Your output for "new users" is incorrect. Your definition of a "new user" is one seen in the last 24 hours, but the time range in your output is more than 24 hours. You'll need to clarify your question, I think.

Comment: I re-computed (manually) count of 'new users' and they are coming same as I have mentioned in output. Please let me know where u think time interval of 24 hrs is being exceeded.
For counts on 2010-01-12  time range would be <= '2010-01-12 18:00:00' and > '2010-01-11 18:00:00'

Comment: Now both tables are labeled as "table2".

Comment: Replying to your reply to me, you've said *"new users are the ones whose uuid appeared in last 24 hours (from now minus the time query is fired) in table2 and was not there before"* Your sample output for new users has dates earlier than 24 hours before the query (13th, 12th, etc.). If a new user is one from the last 24 hours, you can't have that wide a date range -- a new user, by definition, hasn't been seen more than 24 hours ago. (Now, if you mean how many new users *on that date*, that's a totally different requirement with a different answer.)

Comment: definition of user is same (past 24hrs). Except for one ambuquity in statement. I explain it with example.<br> say the date range is 10 th to 13 th jan. and query is fired at 18:00 on any day of the year then (wrt to output):

for 10th time range is 09th Jan 18:00 to 10th Jan 17:59  new_users=3
for 11th time range is 10th Jan 18:00 to 11th Jan 17:59  new_users=2
for 12th time range is 11th Jan 18:00 to 12th Jan 17:59  new_users=0
for 13th time range is 12th Jan 18:00 to 13th Jan 17:59  new_users=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the table on itself to search for entries for the same user that are more than a day old.  When there's no day-old match, fields in the left joined table will be NULL.

For example:

```
select     
  YEAR(cur.ts) as year
, MONTH(cur.ts) as month
, DAY(cur.ts) as day
, case when old.uuid is null then 1 else 0 end as IsNewUser
, count(distinct cur.uuid) as Users
from       table2 cur
left join  table2 old
on         cur.uuid = old.uuid
           and old.ip <> 2
           and old.id > 10
           and cur.ts - old.ts > 1
where      cur.ip <> 2
           and cur.id > 10
group by   year, month, day, IsNewUser
order by   year, month, day, IsNewUser
```

Comment: Does this work on your setup? On mine, even if I change `timestamp` to `ts` (to match the original), I still get "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'old.uuid' in 'field list'".

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Typed it from my head, I switched table1 and table2.   Edited with a better version, though the result is still different from the example answer in the question.

Comment: yes this is working on my machine. But not able to figure out how I change it to my requirements :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not all that familiar with MySQL, but here's how I'd do it in Oracle:

```
SELECT uuid, 'NEW' as user_type FROM
  (SELECT uuid, MAX(ts) as MAX_TS, MIN(ts) as MIN_TS
     FROM TABLE2
     WHERE ID > 10 AND
           IP <> 2
     GROUP BY uuid
     HAVING MAX_TS > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND
            MAX_TS = MIN_TS) nu
UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT uuid, 'REGULAR' as user_type FROM
    (SELECT uuid, MAX(ts) as MAX_TS
       FROM TABLE2
       WHERE ID > 10 AND
             IP <> 2
       GROUP BY uuid) n
     INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                   FROM TABLE2
                   WHERE ID > 10 AND
                          IP <> 2) t
       ON (t.uuid = n.uuid)
     WHERE n.MAX_TS > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND
           t.ts < SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND
           t.ts > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '3' DAY;
```

I can't really see a use for TABLE1 here.  Is it required that you use it?

Don't know if MySQL supports SYSTIMESTAMP or the INTERVAL construct.  Hopefully, though, this will provide you with some ideas.

Comment: in table1 there may days where there is no entry at all. So table1 is used as a seed for dates; and count of users is computed on all those dates that are in table2.